# How do I change image source on click using an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the src attribute on of an image using var cardIndex.

```
<button onclick="changeCard()">Draw Card</button>
<h1 id="theTitle">Click Draw to Begin</h1>
<p id="theDescription">Just press the button below and experience the fun!</p>
<img id="theCard" src=""/>

var cardIndex = 0;
var cards = [
"Card 1",
"Card 2",
"Card 3",
"Card 4",
]; 

var description = [
"Description 1",
"Description 2",
"Description 3",
"Description 4",
];

var source = [
"http://cf.geekdo-images.com/images/pic202889.jpg",
"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/French_suits.svg/300px-French_suits.svg.png",
"http://www.leadersinstitute.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/playing-cards.jpg",
"http://i106.photobucket.com/albums/m275/jogi21/marked-playing-cards.jpg",
]

function changeCard() {
    ++cardIndex;
    if (cardIndex >= cards.length) {
        cardIndex = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById("theDescription").innerHTML =         description[cardIndex];
    document.getElementById("theTitle").innerHTML = cards[cardIndex];
    $('#theCard').attr('src', '');

}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax here:

```
$('#theCard').attr('src', '');
```

How would I make it take the src from my source array using cardIndex as it's value?

Thanks!

Comment: `$('#theCard').attr('src', source[cardIndex])` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `src` to correspond to `cardIndex` like you did with the description and the title:

```
$('#theCard').attr('src', source[cardIndex]);
```

If you don't have jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('thecard').src = source[cardIndex];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried plugging this in as well but the img src still won't change. Not sure why. http://jsfiddle.net/Bum6L/22/

Comment: @user3640511 Ah, that's because you don't have jQuery. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks!!! The JavaScript solution works!!!!  Do you mind briefly explaining or linking to how I would get it working with jQuery if I wanted to? I tried installing by adding this: <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> but don't think it worked.

Comment: Try this: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, plus some code changes to clean things up a bit:

```
var cardIndex = 0;
var cards = [
   { title: "Card 1",
     description: "Description 1",
     source: "http://cf.geekdo-images.com/images/pic202889.jpg"
   },
   { title: "Card 2",
     description: "Description 2",
     source: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/French_suits.svg/300px-French_suits.svg.png"
   },
   { title: "Card 3",
     description: "Description 3",
     source: "http://www.leadersinstitute.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/playing-cards.jpg"
   },
   { title: "Card 4",
     description: "Description 4",
     source: "http://i106.photobucket.com/albums/m275/jogi21/marked-playing-cards.jpg"
   }];

function changeCard() {
   ++cardIndex;
   if (cardIndex >= cards.length) {
       cardIndex = 0;
   }

   var card = cards[cardIndex];
   $('#description').html(card.description);
   $('#theTitle').html(card.title);
   $('#theCard').attr('src', card.source);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is much cleaner. I tried pluggin this solution in but it won't work for some reason. Here's the jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/Bum6L/21/

Answer (score 0):

Adding jQUery to the fiddle should will solve this